# Is there a way to track changes to skills in Live agent?

Tags: user, liveagent, history-tracking, livechattranscript

Use case : Someone unknowingly removed an assigned user from a skill for live agent. We weren't able to find the same in Audit trails. So is there a way to track these changes so that we get to know what is happening in the skills?

I tried to look into SkillUser object but still was not sure who removed User X from the skill. Let me know if there is a way to find this out.